# Selenium Popup support

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have few questions on this as selenium always need windowid to get control over popup.

1-What is the best way to get the windowid of any popup.

3-is it necessary that we must get the windowid of the each & every popup in the view source of the page. if not so what will be work-around.

4-Is window id present in any java-script function? if so ,there is one example I didn’t get Window id of popup

script language="javascript"

begin

function popup(){

window.open('URL/to/popup.html','PopupName','toolbar=0,location=0, status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=345,height=400'); }

// end

/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1-What is the best way to get the windowid of any popup.
>   The best way to get window handle is by name (window.open(url, "Name", options))

```
_selenium.WaitForPopup("Name", "3000");
```

> 3-is it necessary that we must get the windowid of the each & every popup in the view source of the page. if not so what will be work-around.
>   It may not be necessary to have a window name or handle. You can even refer to them as:

```
_selenium.WaitForPopup("", "3000");
```

Comment: Need more clearification on this........ Is _selenium.WaitForPopup() takes selenium RC control that popup.

Comment: You need to make a call to following command `_selenium.SelectWindow("Window Title");` where window title is the title of you popup window.

Comment: ok great , but what about the 3 point answered by you where we do not have the name/id anything for the popup and we use _selenium.WaitForPopup("", "3000"); Is here next step would be _selenium.SelectWindow(""); Pls suggest ,will it woork? thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure about this. As said in my previous comments, the SelectWindow will take the title of the url you are opening in new window. Say for example, the url is [http://www.google.co.in](http://www.google.co.in), the title would be "Google" (The text you see on the title bar.) So the command would be `_selenium.SelectWindow("Google");`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to your written problem

selenium.runscript("popup()");

selenium.waitForPopUp("PopupName","2000");

selenium.selectPopUp("PopupName");

then selenium will get hold of the new window

cheers